# Toenail injury playing soccer

Tags: injury

I was playing soccer and I crashed my foot to the wall and hit my toenail, it was bleeding and a few days past and I saw my toenail black from it began bleeding. Later in the black thing on my toe got bigger and now I'm worried that it will be there forever. What should I do? And answers

Comment: If the "black thing" is under the toenail, that's generally just trapped blood. When the nail eventually falls off, the blood will come with it, no harm. If you're really bothered by it, some people will bore a hole in the nail using a heated paper-clip, but I personally do not recommend it, as it is easy to penetrate too far and burn the nail bed.

Comment: The hole approach should only be considered when the inflammation under the nail is too much, because the swollen tissue can cause discomfort and pain.

Comment: Second the warning. I've seen some nasty infections in the ER from people attempting their own home methods to relieve pressure.

Answer (score 3):

You have an injury. The Internet can't help with a physical injury. You need to go see a doctor and assess the situation.

We have absolutely no way of helping you since you provide little to no valuable information about the injury. And even if we knew, you have no way of knowing who's qualified, and who's pretending.

**We do not give medical advice.**